# Do one dispatch task at a time and cancel current when new starts

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

I have an asynchronous task, I want to perform, and whenever a task is requested, it should make obsolete all previous tasks. This means I want to only ever run one such task at a time and cancel the previous one when a new one starts.

**Example:**

Users presses a button to calculate something. Controller calculates while user changes input data and presses button again. The first calculation should be canceled and a new one should start with the fresh input.

Is this pattern reasonable? What are common patterns to implement this? Is there a straightforward mapping of this to `DispatchQueue`/`OperationQueue`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue` (particularly [its `cancelAllOperations` method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsoperationqueue/1417849-cancelalloperations)). I think, from what I gather of your use case, you can probably encapsulate the task in an `NSOperation` (concrete subclass) and use `NSOperationQueue` to manage it, including canceling it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out! How do people in the real world usually handle a use case like this? When I read tutorials and blog posts where they do network/local background tasks they never seem to invalidate tasks when the context changes. Maybe I misunderstand async but wouldn't kicking off two requests in succession not guarantee the order of their response back on the main thread? This means the first obsolete request could arrive later than the second and the UI would display the wrong data? Am I right that cancelling would be the right approach here?

Comment: @tombardey If you're doing something that's resource-intensive and time-consuming, it's probably a good idea to cancel it before beginning again with new input, assuming the old output would be entirely nonsensical for the new input (and that no output is better than incorrect output). You're right that there's nothing guaranteed with async requests, but use cases vary, and frequently it takes so few resources to perform a background task that people don't worry about it.